# If $f$ is entire such that $|f(z)|\leq C|z|^{5/2}$, $f$ is polynomial of degree two.

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is entire and there exists $C>0$ and $M>0$ such that  $|f(z)|\leq C|z|^{5/2}$ for all $z\in\mathbb{C}$ where $|z|>M$. Prove that $f$ is polynomial of degree two.

I don't have a clear idea but given an entire function and we can bound it $\dfrac{|f(z)|}{|z|^{5/2}}\leq C$, and showing that it has removable singularity at $z=0$, using Riemann's theorem, I can show that $\dfrac{f(z)}{z^{5/2}}$ is a constant by Liouville's theorem. However, I'm not sure what I should do to show that it is intact a polynomial.

Comment: No! $f(z)/z^{5/2}$ is not a holomorphic function in $\Bbb C\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Cauchy's Estimate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Almost certainly, the author of this exercise expected you to use Cauchy's estimates:
$$\frac{|f^{(n)}(a)|}{n!}\le\frac{\sup_t\{|f(a+re^{it}|)\}}{r^n}$$
for $r>0$. Here, then
$$\frac{|f^{(n)}(0)|}{n!}\le\frac{Cr^{5/2}}{r^n}$$
for $r>R$. If $n\ge3$ and we let $r\to\infty$ we get $f^{(n)}(0)=0$.
In the power series $f(z)=\sum a_nz^n$ then $a_3=a_4=\cdots=0$.

Comment: Two questions. Why are we considering $a+re^{it}$? What is $a$ here? And, how do we get the supremum $Mr^{5/2}$?

Comment: @YaG That's *three* questions! $a+re^it$ is the circle, centre $a$ radius $r$. $a=0$ in your problem. The supremum comes from your condition on $f$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n z^n$, and let $g(z) = \sum_{k=0}^\infty a_{k+3} z^k$, so that
$$
[f(z) - a_0 - a_1 z - a_2 z^2] = z^3 g(z).
$$
The function $g$ is entire and, by assumption, $\lim_{|z| \to +\infty} g(z) = 0$:
$$
|g(z)| = \frac{|f(z) - a_0 - a_1 z - a_2 z^2|}{|z|^{5/2}} \cdot \frac{1}{|z|^{1/2}}
\leq \left(C + \frac{|a_0| + |a_1|\, |z| + |a_2|\, |z|^2}{|z|^{5/2}}\right)\frac{1}{|z|^{1/2}} \to 0.
$$ 
Hence, by Liouville's theorem, we must have $g = 0$.

Comment: Would you please explain a little bit more? This does make sense by itself but how did you come up with the $g(z)$ other than the fact that to make a relation to $f(z)$ as you set it up. How is $|z|^{5/2}$ and $C$ used this this case?

Comment: Added a line in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

It may be interesting to note this follows from basic facts about Fourier series (Parseval) with more or less no complex analysis. Say $f(z)=\sum c_nz^n$. Then $$C^2r^5\ge\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}|f(re^{it})|^2\,dt=\sum_j|c_j|^2r^{2j}\ge|c_n|^2r^{2n};$$hence $c_n=0$ for $n\ge3$.

Comment: A lot of complex analysis follows from basic facts about Fourier series.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach can also be made to work, but you need to show that $h(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z^3}$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$.

This can be done as follows:
Let $g(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z^2}$. Then, as $\lim_{z \to 0}g(z)=0$, $g$ has a removable singularity at $z=0$, and if we remove it we have $g(0)=0$.

Now since, after removing the singularity, $g$ is entire and $g(0)=0$, then $h(z)=\frac{g(z)}{z}$ also has a removable singularity at $0$.

Then $h$ becomes an entire function and 
$$\lim_{z \to \infty} h(z)=0$$
From here it is easy to conclude that $h$ is constant.